# Creating os floating window firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to create an OS floating window with Firefox extension? So that the window appears when the browser loses the focus. Googling around didn't bring much. Just need some tutorial / write up on this.

Target OS at the moment - Mac OS X, if it matters.

I apologize if you find this question stupid. At first I'd like to know whether it is possible and feasible to do.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The pixel perfect extension from the Firebug Working Group does exactly this - please see this file for the full implementation:

https://github.com/firebug/pixel-perfect/blob/master/lib/pixel-perfect-popup.js

The core code to creating the pop-up is in a method called 'createPanel' on [line 149](https://github.com/firebug/pixel-perfect/blob/master/lib/pixel-perfect-popup.js#L149-L187):

```
createPanel: function() {
   let browser = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
   let doc = browser.document;

   this.panel = doc.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "panel");
   this.panel.setAttribute("id", "pixel-perfect-panel");
   this.panel.setAttribute("noautohide", "true");
   this.panel.setAttribute("titlebar", "normal");
   this.panel.setAttribute("noautofocus", "true");
   this.panel.setAttribute("label", Locale.$STR("pixelPerfect.title"));
   this.panel.setAttribute("close", "true");
   this.panel.style.border = "0";

   this.panelFrame = doc.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "iframe");
   this.panelFrame.setAttribute("type", "content");
   this.panelFrame.setAttribute("border", "0");
   this.panelFrame.setAttribute("flex", "1");

   // xxxHonza: unregister listeners?
   DomEvents.on(this.panel, "popuphidden", this.onPopupHidden);
   DomEvents.on(this.panel, "popupshown", this.onPopupShown);

   this.panelFrame.setAttribute("src", self.data.url("./popup.html"));
   this.panel.appendChild(this.panelFrame);

   let container = doc.getElementById("mainPopupSet");
   container.appendChild(this.panel);

   // Load content script and handle messages sent from it.
   let { messageManager } = this.panelFrame.frameLoader;
   if (messageManager) {
     let url = self.data.url("popup-frame-script.js");
     messageManager.loadFrameScript(url, false);
     messageManager.addMessageListener("message", this.onMessage);
     messageManager.addMessageListener("sdk/event/ready", this.onPanelReady);
   }

   return this.panel;   
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however the panel loses focus whenever the browser loses it. And selecting just the panel window brings the whole browser window back. My question was - is it possible to have the panel visible on top of other OS window focused? Some kind of a floating or sticky window.